# What's the "System" process on Windows and how to restart it if suspended?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, process, shutdown, resource-monitor

Yesterday, I entered the "Resource Monitor" (using the command "perfmon.exe /res") on Windows 7 in order to check out what process was using my external hard drive, since I wasn't able to remove it safely. I discovered there was a process named "System" reading and writing data. Apparently, it was indexing the drive. In order to stop that, I right-clicked the process and selected "Suspend". Silly thing to do: The whole computer just froze up immediately. I unplugged the hard drive and had to force the shutdown by holding down the power button for some seconds.

My question is: Was there a "proper" way to restart this "System" process? Maybe some kind of keyboard shortcut? And, is it dangerous to force the shutdown the way I did? I mean, dangerous for my internal hard drives or any other part of my PC?

Comment: You could instead have shut down the indexing of the external drive, that would have been sufficient.

Comment: @MSalters How can I do that? I already tried unchecking the "indexing" option on the hard drive general properties window, but it didn't work.

Comment: Start Menu, "Indexing Options", `[Pause]` button?

Comment: @MSalters Great! I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System process ("NT Kernel & System") handles kernel-level things, like drivers, to provide communications between the software and the hardware.

The proper way to restart it is to reboot the computer (aka: the 'system') cleanly.

If the System process locks permanently, then the current session is done for, and a hard reboot is usually the only answer.   Doing that at that point is no more or less "dangerous" than any other unexpected power-off.